# Verifying username and password stored in .txt file for login in PHP

Tags: php, forms, login-script

So for an assignment (hence why I'm storing usernames and pw in a .txt file), I need to create a login page where a user inputs his username and password. The "form" is then sent to a sessionOpen.php file to process if the username and password are contained within a login.txt file.

Here's my sessionOpen.php code:

```
    <?php 
    $myFile = "login.txt";
    $contents = file_get_contents($myFile);
    $contents = explode("\n", $contents);

foreach($contents as $values){
     $loginInfo = explode(":", $values);
        $user = $loginInfo[0];
        $password = $loginInfo[1];

    if($user == $_POST['username'] && $password == $_POST['password']){
        session_start(); 
        header('Location: browse.php');
   }
    else{
        echo '<script>alert("Please verify your username and password.");</script>'
    }
}
    ?>
```

Inside the login.txt file, usernames and password follow the format of `user1:password1`, hence why the `explode(":", $values)`

So normally a session should be created so that the user can now access pages on the website that are locked to people that own an account. The code is not working.

Here is the form if it helps:

```
<form action="sessionOpen.php" method="post">
   <h2>Username:</h2><input type="text" id="username"><br>
   <h2>Password:</h2><input type="password" id="password"><br>
   <input type="submit" value ="submit">
    <input type="reset" value ="reset">
</form>
```

Comment: What's not working?

Comment: simple: no name attributes for your inputs and error reporting would have informed you of it.

Comment: It's not your question but is important to advice: Storing password in plain-text is a bad practice. http://plaintextoffenders.com/faq/devs

Comment: there is syntax error in else statement , please check that , it should work .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your inputs need names.

`$_POST['username']` for example would be sent from an input that has the `name='username'` since none of your inputs have names the form is not submitting any data.

Most browsers have consoles that will allow you to inpsect data being passed. These are handy for coding forms.

Notes from the comments:

- You are also missing the ending semicolon in your `else`.
- Error reporting is also a handy tool to help you figure out stuff like this. You can turn it on by adding these lines to the top of your php script: `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set("display_errors", 1);`

Comment: It works! Thank you so much, I thought id would do the trick but didn't know you needed name also.

Comment: Would my code also be creating a login session with `session_start();`? So I could let other pages be accessible only if a user has `session_start();`

Comment: `session_start()` won't do anything all by itself like you have it. What that function does is start a session that you can write to and then read from later on other pages. For example, after you call it you can create a variable called `$_SESSION['username'] = $username` and then, after calling `session_start()` again on another page `$_SESSION['username']` will be available again. @lesterpierson123